# Quickbooks Error: Business Validation Error: This account number already exists in the QuickBooks chart of accounts

Tags: php, quickbooks, quickbooks-online

I am using the Quickbooks PHP DevKit library to create invoice in Quickbooks.
I am using a French sandbox company and I have this error message :
Business Validation Error: This account number already exists in the QuickBooks chart of accounts. Enter another number.

I think something is missing in my invoice data but I cannot find what !

Below is my code (I used the examples provided in DevKit as a base):

```
$customerRef = '16'; 
$itemRef = '1';
$taxCodeRef = '31';

$InvoiceService = new QuickBooks_IPP_Service_Invoice();

$Invoice = new QuickBooks_IPP_Object_Invoice();

$Line = new QuickBooks_IPP_Object_Line();
$Line->setDetailType('SalesItemLineDetail');
$Line->setAmount(20.0000 * 1.0000 * 0.516129);
$Line->setDescription('Test description goes here.');

$SalesItemLineDetail = new QuickBooks_IPP_Object_SalesItemLineDetail();
$SalesItemLineDetail->setItemRef( $itemRef );
$SalesItemLineDetail->setUnitPrice(20 * 0.516129);
$SalesItemLineDetail->setQty(1.00000);
$SalesItemLineDetail->setTaxCodeRef( $taxCodeRef );

$Line->addSalesItemLineDetail($SalesItemLineDetail);

$Invoice->addLine($Line);

$Invoice->setCustomerRef( $customerRef );


if ($resp = $InvoiceService->add($Context, $realm, $Invoice))
{
    print('Our new Invoice ID is: [' . $resp . ']');
}
else
{
    print($InvoiceService->lastError());
}
```

What could be missing here ?

I add the request sent to Quickbooks and the response received:

Request:

```
<Invoice xmlns="http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3">
    <Line xmlns="http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3">
        <Amount>10.32258</Amount>
        <DetailType>SalesItemLineDetail</DetailType>
        <Description>Test description goes here.</Description>
        <SalesItemLineDetail xmlns="http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3">
            <ItemRef>1</ItemRef>
            <UnitPrice>10.32258</UnitPrice>
            <Qty>1</Qty>
            <TaxCodeRef>31</TaxCodeRef>
        </SalesItemLineDetail>
    </Line>
    <CustomerRef>16</CustomerRef>
</Invoice>
```

Response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<IntuitResponse xmlns="http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3" time="2017-02-01T02:08:16.198-08:00">
    <Fault type="ValidationFault">
        <Error code="6000" element="">
            <Message>A business validation error has occurred while processing your request</Message>
            <Detail>Business Validation Error: Ce numéro de compte existe déjà dans le plan comptable de QuickBooks. Entrez un autre numéro.</Detail>
        </Error>
    </Fault>
</IntuitResponse>
```

The response for Item id=1

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<IntuitResponse xmlns="http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3" time="2017-02-01T09:28:05.599-08:00">
    <QueryResponse startPosition="1" maxResults="1">
        <Item domain="QBO" sparse="false">
            <Id>1</Id>
            <SyncToken>1</SyncToken>
            <MetaData>
                <CreateTime>2017-01-10T23:31:30-08:00</CreateTime>
                <LastUpdatedTime>2017-01-18T07:00:19-08:00</LastUpdatedTime>
            </MetaData>
            <Name>Ventes bonbons</Name>
            <Description>Frandises 100g</Description>
            <Active>true</Active>
            <FullyQualifiedName>Ventes bonbons</FullyQualifiedName>
            <Taxable>false</Taxable>
            <SalesTaxIncluded>false</SalesTaxIncluded>
            <UnitPrice>10</UnitPrice>
            <Type>Service</Type>
            <IncomeAccountRef name="701100 Ventes de Produits finis (ou groupe) A 20%">71</IncomeAccountRef>
            <PurchaseTaxIncluded>false</PurchaseTaxIncluded>
            <PurchaseCost>5</PurchaseCost>
            <ExpenseAccountRef name="607100 Achats de Marchandises (ou groupe) A">29</ExpenseAccountRef>
            <TrackQtyOnHand>false</TrackQtyOnHand>
            <SalesTaxCodeRef name="SalesTaxCodeRef">31</SalesTaxCodeRef>
            <PurchaseTaxCodeRef name="PurchaseTaxCodeRef">31</PurchaseTaxCodeRef>
            <ItemCategoryType>Product</ItemCategoryType>
        </Item>
    </QueryResponse>
</IntuitResponse>
```

Thanks in advance for your help !

Comment: Post the XML request sent to QuickBooks. Post the XML response received from QuickBooks.

Comment: @KeithPalmerJr. Thank You ! I added the requested information in my question

Comment: Are you positive that item Id=1 actually exists? I know France locales have some special requirements here, so I wonder if maybe the item doesn't exist or something?

Comment: Have you tried specifying TransactionLocationType in the invoice as well? TransactionLocationType:
optional
minor version 4
String, default is WithinFrance 
The account location. Valid values include:
WithinFrance
FranceOverseas
OutsideFranceWithEU
OutsideEU

Comment: Thank you @KeithPalmerJr. . Yes Item id=1 actually exists. I also tried setting TransactionLocationType to WithinFrance but I have the same issue. I am pretty sure that it is something relationed to France locales requirements but I have no answer from Quickbooks about this issue... I will continue my investigations. If you have another idea do not hesitate! I really appreciate your help ! :-)

Comment: Can you post the XML response of what the item looks like when you query for item id=1?

Comment: @KeithPalmerJr. I added the XML response to my message. Thank you !

Comment: @KeithPalmerJr.  Thank you very much for your help ! Finally it was an issue with quickbooks sandbox company!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I got the answer from QuickBooks that there is a bug in sandbox French company. Using a trial account in production mode, I have no issue.